# Did Apocalypse enhance mutants' superpowers permanently?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

[Is Charles Xavier the only one whose powers were not permanently affected?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154811/is-charles-xavier-the-only-one-whose-powers-were-not-permanently-affected)

This question assumes that Apocalypse enhanced mutants' superpowers *permanently*. Is this true? I want proper citation.

I am skeptical because if Magneto could continue to be able to single-handedly create apocalyptic mayhem, those future sentinels in *X-Men: Days of the Future Past* movie shouldn't have been a big deal. But, it can be plot inconsistency or Magneto's old age.

Comment: The sentinels were a different timeline.

Comment: @Bellerophon: the future ones, anyway.

Comment: I can't close this as duplicate, but you are basically asking the other question over again.

Comment: X-Men: Apocalypse happened in the new timeline. If DoFP never happened, then the new timeline would've never coalesced wherein Apocalypse awakens. Apocalypse awakening is what lends itself to Magneto getting the pep talk he required to begin exhibiting the full extent of his abilities.